# Executing code when accessing API controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponse

I have the following code:

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("session").FirstOrDefault();
var isAuthenticated = _userService.IsAuthenticated(cookie);

if (!isAuthenticated) 
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "");
```

I'd like this code to execute as soon as any part of my api is called. I havn't found any good solutions or ways to do this so i thought i would ask here instead.

(what I do now is execute the code in every get/post/put/delete which is horrible).

Comment: A global Authentication Filter is what you are looking for. Web API 2 Message Lifecycle: http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf

Comment: I don't want to use identity at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the best solution for my problem was the following code:

```
public class CookieFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        CookieHeaderValue cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("session").FirstOrDefault();
        var isAuthenticated = UserService.IsAuthenticated(cookie);

        return isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best place to solve this would be an authorization filter attribute. See [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters).

The subject is too broad to repeat here in its entirety, but it comes down to creating an attribute:

```
public class CookieAuthenticationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // your cookie code
    }
}
```

And applying it to the controller or action methods:

```
[YourCookieAuthentication]
```

But be sure to read the link.

Comment: I've read that article a few times but I want to be able to return a HttpResponseMessage right away and using an attribute doesn't allow me to use "Request"

Comment: Yeah it does, by setting the error result: `context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult` and `AuthenticationFailureResult : IHttpActionResult` which has a `Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync()`.

Comment: Yes but it checks for authorized in the header afterwards and I'm not setting the authorization header at all, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ActionFilter or AuthorizationFilter for this purpose. These are attribute classes that you can use on specific controllers/actions or globally. So you don't need to repeat the code for every action.

See this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) for details. It shows the general authentication/authorization flow in ASP.NET Web API and how you can customize it.